# prevent overwriting in implicit operator

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I have a small class, let's call uomvalue, which contains a UOM and a Value field.

I have an implicit operator which converts a double to the Value field, when directly applied.

So if I use it the "normal" way, all is fine:

```
obj.UOM = "ft"; 
obj.Value = 123.4; //normal assignment
```

My problem is that when I assign using the implicit operator:

```
obj = 123.4; //impl op assignement
```

...the whole object is replaced, and any assignment I may have already made to the UOM is lost.

This may fall into the "dumb question" category because I really haven't spent any time to figure this out, but is there a simple way to do this where I can keep the old value for the UOM when the impl. op. is used?

Comment: Your `uomvalue` class should probably be an immutable struct. And `UOM` isn't a good field name either.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Correct.  It should be called `Unit`.

Comment: Ok let's say the class was generated from an xml based standard, thus I didn't have a say in the design. Ok, go ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest answer: don't have an implicit conversion from `double`. Implicit conversions like this are *almost* always a bad idea in my view. (There are exceptions, but it doesn't sound like this is one of them.)

It feels to me that implicit conversions are also more appropriate for immutable types, where the situation you're describing simply can't occur. It seems to me that your code would definitely be clearer *without* the implicit conversion. For example:

```
obj = SomeClass.FromDouble(123.4);
```

is now obvious in terms of what it's doing.

And no, you can't write an implicit operator which tries to preserve an existing value. After all, the conversion all happens before the assignment - nothing in the expression `123.4` knows anything about `obj`... so you'd have to make the assignment operator itself know that it should use some part of value of the variable which is *going* to be assigned as part of working out the value *to* be assigned. That becomes problematic when there *isn't* such a value beforehand.

All of that's getting way to complicated: ditch the conversion :)

Comment: I'll add one more thing- the UOM can be set on all classes through use of defaults, so very often the uom is not explicitly set, and expected to be teh default uom.

Comment: @boomhauer: That doesn't change my answer at all, to be honest.

Comment: But anyway, you answered the (dumb) question of whether we could access some of the "original" data. Answer goes to you sir ;)

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the implicit cast.

Your implicit cast destroys information (namely, the `UOM` field).
Implicit casts should always preserve all information in the source object.

If the target type is narrower than the source type, use an explicit cast.

This is why `uint` has an implicit cast to `double` but not to `int`.

---

Also, since your type represents a value, it should be immutable.

Answer (score 2):

I can remember a primary school teacher who would respond to any answer that ommited a unit when needed, asking "What? Sheep? Meters? Pounds? Years?".

You've a class that is meant to have the answer to that question, and the implicit operator removes that. If you do:

```
x = 6.0
```

You are saying "x is now equal to 6.0". Not "x is now equal to 6.0 is those aspects of it that are numeric, and unchanged in the other ways", but just "x is now equal to 6.0"

For this reason, even if what you were attempting was possible, it would be a bad design for an explicit operator, never mind an implicit one.

The other way around is another matter. If we did:

```
UnitMeasure um = new UnitMeasure(6.0, Units.Meter);
double d = (double)um;
```

Then it's a bit clearer to the caller of the code that when we assign 6.0meters to a double, that the double now contains 6.0. I'd still have it explicit rather than implicit (it loses information) and some would be wary enough of cast overrides to still avoid it (there are good arguments either way), but at least it means something.

At the end of the day, you are writing code for both humans and machines. If you don't write something meaningful, or even worse force others to write something that isn't meaningful, then your design could be improved, and "this combination of a number and a unit equals 6" is not meaningful.

---

That aside, the reason the implicit operators (and explicit operators for that matter) overwrite like they do, is that that is exactly what they are for. `(int)3.2` creates a brand new `int`. `(double)76` creates a brand new double.

There is no difference between:

```
obj = 123.4;
```

And

```
UnitMeasure temp = new UnitMeasure(123.4);
obj = temp;
```

How can that not over-write obj?

The only forms of casts that don't create a new object are up-casts and down-casts that are changing the way an object is used, rather than the object:

```
string s = "abc";
object o = s;//implicit - but s was already an object!
string s2 = (string)o;//explicit - but o was already a string! (and it would throw otherwise).
```

These forms don't change some parts of the object, because they don't change **any** part of the object.

At the end of the day, you're asking how to have an implicit cast that doesn't behave like an implicit cast. Thankfully, you can't.